# Joining Windows 10 VirtualBox image to an active directory domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, virtualbox

I'm not sure if this is the correct forum (please advise if not). I have a simple task - to add a 'virgin' Windows 10 virtual machine (using Oracle VirtualBox) to our Active Directory domain so I can test something on it. The VM works okay in that it starts up and allows me to log in as a local user, but when we try to add it to the domain we get the message "That domain couldn't be found".

The host machine is connected to the domain and works normally. The VM can also access the internet, so it appears that networking between the VM and host are okay. However the VM can only 'see' itself on the network.

I'm a novice with Windows 10 networking, so any guidance will be appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to have a simple solution - when asked for the domain to join it has to be qualified (in our case) with a .local suffix. I was trying to add it to MyDomain instead of MyDomain.local

Answer (score 0):

I did the following using VBox Extensions:

Open the Network from the Tools.  There are four showing on my VitualBox Manager.  Look at the properties.  There are a couple of 192.168 IPv4 addresses listed and a couple of 169.254 addresses listed. The fourth adapter, (labeled VistualBox Host-Only Ehternetw Adapter #3) shows my home domain IP range.  I checked that box.  Then under the Adapter tab, Configure Adapter Manually (it was already set up but if it is set wrong, you may want to configure it manually to point to your domain gateway DHCP)  Secondly, under the DHCP Server Tab, there is a setting to open the server address and the lower address bound.  Again this was set with a default value.

Now, with the 4th network adapter turned on, when I run the box, try to ping the domain server, the ping responds without a  timeout.

Right click MyPC in the Windows Explorer, go to properites, then System Properties and select Computer name.   Change the WORKGROUP default name to point to your domain address (which maybe MyDOMAIN.local)  Make sure you have domain admin permission to add the box to the active directory.  Using that login, add the VBox to the domain.

Restart.

When it comes back up, login with your domain user name from the person with the rights to add you to the domain and have that person enable the server for you to administrate or use or whatever purpose it might be you have in mind for that VBox on that domain.